# How to query distinct from AWS log insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I need to query data from lambda using AWS Cloudwatch log insights.
The query syntax provide by aws doesn't have distinct.

Only support (count_distinct(fieldname))

ref. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

**Example data**

Column # @timestamp @ message

> 1 2020-02-17T13:33:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_A_
>
> 2 2020-02-17T11:32:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_B_
>
> 3 2020-02-17T11:31:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_B_
>
> 4 2020-02-17T11:30:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_C_
>
> 5 2020-02-17T11:29:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_A_

**Expected result**

> 1 2020-02-17T13:33:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_A_
>
> 2 2020-02-17T11:32:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_B_
>
> 4 2020-02-17T11:30:29.049+07:00 [INFO] 2020 Partition key: ABC12345_C_

If usage normal SQL syntax look like below.

> select distinct(uuid) as uuid, max(time) as time
> from table_name group by uuid order by time desc

Comment: I was able to get the distinct rows using count_distinct. You could try something similar to this:
`stats count_distinct(@logStream) as IngestionTime by @ingestionTime, @logStream as LogStream
| sort @ingestionTime desc
| limit 10`

Answer (score 35):

You can use

```
| stats count(*) by fieldname
```

This allows to list the distinct values in `fieldname`.

Comment: easiest and fastest way to get distinct field values

Comment: stats remove the display of the fields :(

Answer (score 16):

You can use **[Non-Aggregation Functions in the Stats Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)** like below

```
stats latest(@timestamp) as @latestTimestamp by @message
| display @latestTimestamp, @message
```

Answer (score 8):

You can now use the `dedup` keyword to remove duplicates.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, order_id
| sort @timestamp desc 
| dedup order_id
```

From what I can tell, it needs to be the last operator in the query.

Comment: In December 2023 this is the most elegant and efficient solution

Comment: I didn't know about dedup.  It's awesome.